# Adding custom validation checks (VB for applications)

Tags: excel, vba

I have fairly sophisticated validation checks that I'd like to add to an Excel sheet. I prefer to code these rather than to use Excel's standard validation.

I am looking for a basic VBA validation example (sort of a "hello world") so that I can generate my more sophisticated validation off of it. To make things concrete let's say that if I have this sheet:

```
   |     A        |       B        |       c       |
   -------------------------------------------------
1  |Name          |Length          |               |
   -------------------------------------------------
2  |Johnny        |6               |               |
   -------------------------------------------------
3  |Alex          |2               |               |
   -------------------------------------------------
```

then I want to mark a cell in the "B" column as invalid if it does not match the length of the of the string in column "A". In the example above, the B3 cell should be marked as invalid since its value (2) does not match the length of "Alex" (4).

Comment: That's a bit broad - it would help to describe in more detail exactly what you'd like to do, and how you want to trigger the validation.

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks, please take another look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to capture users making changes to cell values then you'd use the sheet's `Worksheet_Change` event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range, rw As Range

    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A2:B1000"))
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        'assuming Target is a contiguous rectangular range
        For Each c In rng.Columns(1)                 
            Debug.Print c.Address()
            Set rw = c.EntireRow
            If rw.Cells(2).Value <> Len(rw.Cells(1).Value) Then
                rw.Cells(2).Interior.Color = vbRed
            Else
                rw.Cells(2).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
            End If
        Next c
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that if cells will be changing as the result of a formula recalculating then you'll need to use the `Worksheet_Calculate` event.